# How to force nginx to send headers with empty content body?

Tags: nginx

The nginx close connection if status code is 200 and there is no body. But my handler set 202 code and there is no body. In this case nginx also close connection. So client app can not distinguish 200 and 202 status codes because it just see closed connection.

Is there a way to force nginx to deliver status codes to client with empty content body?

*UPD* Configuration for this part of app:

```
    location = /file/add {
            keepalive_timeout 0;

            set $upload_progress_fallback_code       360;
            set $upload_progress_memcached_servers   "127.0.0.2:11211";
            set $upload_progress_memcached_namespace server.name;
            set $upload_progress_memcached_compress_threshold 10000;

            error_page 360 = @root2;
            perl UploadProgress::handle;
    }
```

Comment: Your app should check status. Show your nginx config

Comment: What you mean? My app return status: 'return HTTP_ACCEPTED;'

Answer (score 0):

I have found next solution (for mod_perl2 handler)

```
    if( $track->{ stage } ne 'finish' ) {
        # ...report we are in progress
        $r->status( HTTP_ACCEPTED );
    }
    else {
        # ...or report we are done
        $r->status( OK );
    }


    $r->send_http_header;
    return;
```

Link to [DOC](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html)